# Should I create a new in app purchase for every new build to upload on iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app

I am uploading a new on iTunesConnect. This is the second time I am going to upload a build before that I upload a build with in app purchase creating a new in-app purchase and that in-app purchase was approved and the build was also ready for sale.

But when I am going to upload a new build ( for second time ), I can't see the previous approved in-app purchase which I added for the first build.

So, my question is, do I need to create a new in-app purchase for a new build to upload?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The Answer is, **NO** you don’t

In-App and the App itself can (but must not) be reviewed independent from each other.

One you got you  in-app approved. It will stay in `Ready-For-Sale` for as long as the app lives

As long as it’s approved within the first build. You can safely update/modify your app at any time. It wouldn’t reflect the in-app purchase.

Only when they update their privacy, policy or terms of agreement. You’ll have to agree in the developer console and everything will be back to normal

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, I don't need to select any in-app purchase while uploading the build for second time, right? I just need to select the build and submit it for review, right?

Comment: If the in-app purchases status is green and ready for sale in **Features > In App Purchases** then yes, nothing is needed

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very helpful!

Comment: Glad it helped, giving the correct answer check mark helps me continue :)

Comment: I would like to give the correct answer mark as my reputation is low, I can't. I will upvote your answer from my original account.